# Between in query builder and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

User go te the form of advanced search. He can input few values, and some range slider price(jquery ui widget). Then in Controller I get values and want find all rows, where at least one condition will mathced. 
Here is code of repository:

```
public function advancedSearch($bag, $startPrice, $targetPrice)
{
    $parameters = ['bag' => $bag];
    $query = $result = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('t')
        ->from('VputiTripBundle:Trip', 't');
    $query->orWhere('t.bag = :bag');
    $query->orWhere(
        $query->expr()->between('t.price', $startPrice, $targetPrice)
    );
    $result = $query
        ->setParameters($parameters)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

Whe start- and target- price equal to 271 and 278, I get post where price 300. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just given this a quick look but I think it has to do with the fact that you're using `orWhere()`. Shouldn't it be `andWhere()`?

Right now your query is probably returning all results where `t.bag = :bag` `OR` where the price is between `$startPrice` and `$targetPrice`, which explains the behavior you described. I'm guessing you also get results where the price is right but where the `bag` property doesn't match the `$bag` parameter.

Edit:

Since some of the filters might not be set, you only want to apply them when they are. I think the best way to go here is to build your query dynamically by using PHP `if` statements. For example:

```
public function advancedSearch($bag, $startPrice, $targetPrice)
{
    $parameters = array();

    // $query = $result = $this->getEntityManager() ... etc

    if (!empty($bag)) {
        $query->andWhere('t.bag = :bag');
        $parameters['bag'] = $bag;
    }

    if (!empty($startPrice) && !empty($targetPrice)) {
        $query->andWhere(
            $query->expr()->between('t.price', $startPrice, $targetPrice)
        );
    }

    // $result = $query->setParameters($parameters) ... etc

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, my mistake. But what if I want to get results only for pricesm and bag will be null?

Comment: So you want the QueryBuilder equivalent of `WHERE price BETWEEN :startPrice AND :targetPrice AND (bag = :bag OR bag IS NULL)`?

Comment: yes, something like this, the issue is, I will getting multiple inputs in controller(bag, price etc.), and then I need to find all posts where at exist at leas one of all these stuff...

Comment: Now you're confusing me. Perhaps you can update your question with the exact behavior you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I will do this at minute)

Comment: Ah wait. I think I understand what you want. You have a number of filters (such as bag and a price range), and you want to apply them to the results, but only the filters that are set. Is that correct? Give me a moment to update my answer.

Comment: yes filers, you are right. sorry my English not good, I it hard to me to express my opinion) I update my question.)

Comment: Don't worry ;) I've updated my answer... does this solve your problem?

Comment: here is query for that code SELECT t FROM VputiTripBundle:Trip t WHERE t.bag = :bag AND (t.price BETWEEN AND )

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the `$startPrice` and `$targetPrice` variables? Perhaps they're not `null` but an empty string. In that case, replace the `!==` with `!=`.

Comment: yes it empty strings, and if I dont point the bag it empty string too, so it includes to query, because !== .